# JavaFX Can i repaint a Stage?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

[image]After you put some values in the programm over the keyboard, the stage started, But at the same time i would like to have the stage is open, user can put some values again and the stage restart.

Is that possible?

I would like to do something like this:

```
     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    javafx.application.Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (TastaturEingabe.readBoolean("Möchten Sie ein neues Diagramm zeichnen?")) {

                // Input through keyboard
                readInputJahrgang(vintage, FIRST_PROMPT);
                readInputLager(vintage, FIRST_PROMPT);
                primaryStage.hide();
            } else {
                primaryStage.close();
            }
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't understand.. Keyboard input is done to the console? In common case, you can set new scene to stage.. you can hide/show stage..

Comment: I changed it. Hope its more clear now :/ 
But it doesnt work. My Stage freezes and i cant do anything. In the other case (if readBoolean is true) the stage closed and nothing more is possible. 
I think i need to do something to come to the beginning of the startmethod, so i can do the same again. But in this case, i dont know how.

Sorry, if this are stupid questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a wrong design of interacting between user and application.

```
javafx.application.Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
```

will be run on JFX thread, and while you are talking with a user in a command line, UI will be frozen.

You can talk to a user via comandline in a separate thread, which can use runLater() calls to inform JFX, about new user input.

So, you can create a separate thread in a start method, and put

```
readInputJahrgang(vintage, FIRST_PROMPT);
readInputLager(vintage, FIRST_PROMPT);
```

calls in its runnable.

When user input new info, which is needed to redraw a UI, call runLater().

In common case, you don't need to force JavaFX to redraw anything. It will do everything by itself

Comment: I think the problem was, that i have not work with threads yet. Thank you for your help. It works!!! Awesome.

Comment: The main concern about UI building - is a response to user, when your program is doing some useful stuff. And this task requires work with threads. When one thread serves user need, and others - do a useful work. And its coordination - is one of main issues. The threading - is  a meaningfull knowledge for efficient UI building. Try to look at javafx.concurrent package for more info about threading in JFX